# Count string appears in list and copy along with number of time it appear into strongly type list- c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of string containing different words and most of words are repeating.
Now I want to copy all the string from list and save into strongly type list with string itself and no of times it appears in list. I need to use LINQ.

### Model class

```
 public class WordCount
{
    public WordCount()
    { }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string word { get; set; }

    public int counter { get; set; }
}
```

### My current list

```
 private List<string> _WordContent = new List<string>();
```

### New strongly type list  ?????????

```
 public void CountWordInWebSiteContent()
    {

        var counts = _WordContent
                    .GroupBy(w => w)
                    .Select(g => new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                    .ToList();


        List<WordCount> myWordList = new List<WordCount>();



        var a = "d";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create objects of `WordCount`  while projecting grouped result:

Here is using Lambda Expression syntax:

```
.Select((g,index) => new WordCount
                         { 
                           word = g.Key,
                           counter = g.Count(),
                           ID =index 
        }).ToList();
```

Using query expression syntax:

```
int Id=1;
var counts  = from word in _WordContent
              group word by word into g 
              select new WordCount
                         { 
                            ID= Id++,
                            word = g.Key,
                            counter = g.Count() 
                         };
```

Comment: I want to use linq not lambda expression unless it is require in following; (from words in _WordContent
                        group words by words into grouped
                        select grouped).ToList();

Comment: @toxic i added query syntax as well for you

Answer (score 0):

many thanks to Ehsan

complete answer as following;

```
 myWordList= (from words in _WordContent
                    group words by words into grouped
                    select grouped).Select((g,index) => new WordCount
                     { 
                       word = g.Key,
                       counter = g.Count(),
                       ID =index 
                    }).ToList();
```